# Limiting the size of a string for serialization in C++

Tags: c++, serialization

I have a struct which represents a file header for the [M64](http://tasvideos.org/EmulatorResources/Mupen/M64.html) input recording format.

The data can serialized back into a file, but the string values are limited in length (example: the ROM name can only be 32 bytes including null terminator). So how should I go about implementing this? I see 3 methods:

- make the string private and create a setter and getter, handling accordingly
- create a wrapper class around `std::string`, handling accordingly
- check when I serialize and handle accordingly

Note: "handle accordingly" could mean either throwing an error or truncating the string

Which is considered best practice? Is there something else I haven't considered?

Comment: wrapper seems fine, but you could also wrap an array! extra heap allocation is best avoided when possible.

Comment: Your first alternative is almost certainly the best. The name having maximum length is part of the type's [class invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_invariant), and creating a wrapper type that would only be used a single time is overengineering.